# How to post all data of form to php all together using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form

```
<form>

Name <input name=nm type=text">
Password <input name=pass type=password >
```

I want to send the value of both the field, how to do this using js

Comment: You can use `new FormData(form)` where `form` is a variable containing a reference to the `<form>` element.

Comment: Hey thanks, it's done , thankyou for your valuable time sir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it using serialize()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").text($("form").serialize());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Password: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
</form>

<button>Serialize form values</button>
body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="nm" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="password" name="password" value="Mouse"><br>
</form>

<button>Serialize form values</button>

<div></div>
</body>
</html>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you